# Scroll if any alphanumeric character or symbol is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am writing a JS code that scrolls a container is any alphanumeric character or symbol is pressed.

This is what I came up with:

```
var $q = $('input#q');
$q.on('keydown', function (e) {
    var reMatch = /[!-~]/.exec(e.which);
    if (typeof reMatch != 'null' && reMatch.length > 0) {
        $('#container').animate({scrollTop: 410}, 500);
        $(this).off('keydown');
    }
}).focus();
```

But this executes for all keys like shift, tab, enter etc ...

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `keydown` is triggered when the user presses a key (before releasing it). `e.which` is a numeric representation of they key pressed, it couldn't possibly contain a character like `!` or `~`. Also, to get the `!` character you'd have to push "Shift" and then press "1", these would both trigger keydown. I think you need to clarify a bit exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Well, I followed what you said in your last (deleted) comment and used `var reMatch = /[!-~]/.exec(String.fromCharCode(e.which));` which works. After `shift` is ignored, ascii of `!` is passed which triggers scroll. But arrow keys are still somehow triggering the scroll, is there a way to solve this issue too?

Comment: I have posted an answer that will work for the letters, pressing the number keys (including if shift is held down), and pressing the numpad number keys. Does this cover what you are looking for? Also, you'll find that `fromCharCode(e.which)` will not return what you expect for many keys.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to figure out your actual goal... is it basically pressing anything that inserts a character to the input field?

Comment: Yes! Its for an input form, when user starts typing, form should scroll at top of page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.which gives a numeric representation of the key pressed. The number keys are represented by 48-57 (or 96-105 on the keypad) while letters are represented by 65-90

Try this:

```
var $q = $('input#q');
$q.on('keydown', function (e) {
    var val = e.which;
    var num = (val > 47 && val < 58 || val > 95 && val < 106);
    var letter = (val > 64 && val < 91);
    if (num || letter) {
        $('#container').animate({scrollTop: 410}, 500);
        $(this).off('keydown');
    }
}).focus();
```

---

You could do this for it to work with anything that creates an input in the text field:

```
var $q = $('input#q');
$q.on('input', function (e) {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: 410
    }, 500);
    $(this).off('input');
}).focus();
```

but this will not work for IE versions less than 9. Although if you look, you can find shims. [Here is an example](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html)

---

You could do this, but it would not scroll immediately if the user is holding a key down for a long time (until the user releases the key).

```
var $q = $('input#q');
var qval = $q.val()
$q.on('keyup', function (e) {
    if(qval != $q.val()) {
        $('#container').animate({scrollTop: 410}, 500);
        $(this).off('keyup');
    }
}).focus();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am just curious, why did my re in comment above matches arrow keys?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode()` doesn't really return what you expect for many things. You can alert it if you want to see what it's actually returning.

Comment: @Sourabh, I've added a couple different solutions that you may be interested in.

Comment: `'input'` === awesome !!
Thanks for the help smerny! `input` event listener solved all the problems.